# Sysprep on Windows 7 for a non-windows admin?

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

I'm needing to use sysprep to deploy some Windows 7 machines. I can't find any resources that explain this very easily. In particular, I've loaded all of the programs I want for the image onto a computer. If I want to use prepares this for cloning onto 200 other machines, what steps would I need to take?

Or do I need to start again, creating the image using 'audit' mode? The machines I'm using come pre-configured from the manufacturer with a host of custom drivers that wouldn't be fun to re-install - I'd rather use their base image to build upon.

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: What approach are you planning to use to activation? That has implications as to if you can use the manufacturer's image.

Comment: Each machine has a key sticker on it. The user will enter the key when turning on the machine for the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Askvictor,

The following KB (Knowledge Base) article from Microsoft should assists you in [using the Sysprep tool to automate a successful deployment of Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577).

Also, there are several new features that are available with Windows 7 that will assist you with the deployment and management of a large number of workstations. Enterprise IT infrastructures are increasingly complex to manage. The Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack (MDOP) is a dynamic desktop solution that is available as a subscription for Software Assurance customers. The solution suite enhances application deployment and compatibility, increases IT responsiveness and end user uptime, and helps reduce total cost of ownership (TCO) of your desktop software and IT management.

Also now available is MDT 2010 (Microsoft Deployment Tool) which will help you create images and automate the OS and application installations, data migration, and desktop configuration process. 
Should you require additional assistance and guidance, Microsoft does have an official Windows 7 Support Forum specifically for IT Pros . It is supported by product specialists as well as engineers and support teams. You may want to also check the threads available there for additional assistance and feedback.

Jessica
Microsoft Windows Client Team

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the KB article Jessica referenced, you might take a look at this technet webcast:

[TechNet Webcast: Everything You Wanted to Know About Windows 7 Deployment in 90 Minutes (Level 300)](http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/technetwindows7.aspx?tab=Webcasts&seriesid=141&webcastid=12695)